# Tic Tack Toe game in applet: image not working

Tags: java, jframe, japplet

```
/**
 *
 * @author suchit
 * Date : 11/25/2012
 * History :
 */

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


public class TicTacToe extends JApplet {

    static Cell[] arrCell=new Cell[9];
    static int fsize=400;
    static char drawCh;
    static JLabel lblMsg = new JLabel("Start the game: Player1 mark X");
    static boolean gameOver = false;
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame("TicTacToe Game");
    JButton btnStart = new JButton("New Game");
    static Image bg;
    static File fn;
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public TicTacToe()      //default constructor
    {
      JPanel objPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3, 0, 0));     //creates j panel
      for(int i=0;i<9;i++)              // add nine objects on jpanel
        {
            arrCell[i]=new Cell();
        }  
      for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
            objPanel.add(arrCell[i]);
        }

       objPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));      // create border
       //objPanel.add(btnStart);//add button
       objPanel.add(lblMsg);    // Display message
       //btnStart.addActionListener(new StartAction());       // Add action listener to the button



 // Place the panel and the label to the applet
        add(objPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(lblMsg, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        //add(btnStart,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    } // end of constructor
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        frame.setSize(new Dimension(fsize,fsize));
        //frame.setPreferredSize();
        TicTacToe objTicTacToe = new TicTacToe();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.add(objTicTacToe);



    } // end of main

class StartAction implements ActionListener
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            fsize++;
            drawCh='A';
            gameOver=false;
            for(int i=0; i<9;i++)
            {
                arrCell[i].value='A';
            }
            frame.setSize(new Dimension(fsize,fsize));
            lblMsg.setText("Player1's Turn: mark X");
        }
    } // end of class StartAction

    public static boolean isGameOver()          // checks wather any one won and game is over
 {
     boolean winner=false;
     boolean Draw=false;
     //if any three consucutive rows will have same value then player won the game
     if((arrCell[0].value ==drawCh && arrCell[1].value== drawCh &&arrCell[2].value==drawCh))
     {
         winner=true;
     }
     if((arrCell[3].value ==drawCh && arrCell[4].value== drawCh &&arrCell[5].value==drawCh))
     {
         winner=true;
     }
     if((arrCell[6].value ==drawCh && arrCell[7].value== drawCh &&arrCell[8].value==drawCh))
     {
         winner=true;
     }
     if((arrCell[0].value ==drawCh && arrCell[3].value== drawCh &&arrCell[6].value==drawCh))
     {
         winner=true;
     }
     if((arrCell[1].value ==drawCh && arrCell[4].value== drawCh &&arrCell[7].value==drawCh))
     {
         winner=true;
     }
     if((arrCell[2].value ==drawCh && arrCell[5].value== drawCh &&arrCell[8].value==drawCh))
     {
         winner=true;
     }
     if((arrCell[0].value ==drawCh && arrCell[4].value== drawCh &&arrCell[8].value==drawCh))
     {
         winner=true;
     }
     if((arrCell[2].value ==drawCh && arrCell[4].value== drawCh &&arrCell[6].value==drawCh))
     {
         winner=true;
     }

     if(winner)
     {
         if(drawCh=='X')
            lblMsg.setText("Player1 Won, Game Over");   // player 1 won
         else if(drawCh=='O')
             lblMsg.setText("Player2 Won, Game Over");  // player 2 won
         else
             winner=false;      // no one won, its a default values of all boxes

     }
     for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
     {
         if(arrCell[i].value=='A')
         {
            Draw=false;
            break;
         }
         else
            {
            Draw=true;
            }
     }
if(Draw)
{
    lblMsg.setText("Game Over : Result Draw");
}
     System.out.println("Draw="+Draw);
     return winner;

 } // end of isGameOver()
 public static class Cell extends JPanel
 {
     char value='A';
     public Cell()
     {
         this.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1)); // Set cell's border
         this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
         addMouseListener(new MouseListener());
     }

     private class MouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
 /** Handle mouse click on a cell */
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

 if(!gameOver && value=='A')       
 {
        if(drawCh=='X')     // set the message for the next player and current image to draw
        {
            lblMsg.setText("Player1's Turn: mark X");
            drawCh='O';
        }

        else if(drawCh=='O')    // set the message for the next player and current image to draw
        {
            lblMsg.setText("Player2's Turn: mark O");
            drawCh='X';
        }
        else        // set the message for the next player and current image to draw at start of the game
        {
         drawCh='X';
         lblMsg.setText("Player2's Turn: mark O");
        }       
        repaint();
        value=drawCh;
    }

 }   // end of mouseClicked

} // end of MouseListener

      protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
      {
         try {
             //super.paintComponent(g);
             System.out.println("gameOver = "+gameOver);
           System.out.println("Drawing");
           if (drawCh == 'X')      // draw X
              {
               fn = new File("D:\\Java Projects\\HW9\\images\\tictactoeX.png");
               bg = ImageIO.read(fn);
               g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, this);
               //g.drawLine(10, 10, getWidth() - 10, getHeight() - 10);
                // g.drawLine(getWidth() - 10, 10, 10, getHeight() - 10);
              }
           else if (drawCh == 'O') // Draw O
              {
               fn = new File("D:\\Java Projects\\HW9\\images\\tic-tac-toe-O.png");   
               bg = ImageIO.read(fn);
               g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, this);
               //g.drawOval(10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20);
              }

           gameOver=isGameOver();
         } // end of paint component
         catch (IOException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(TicTacToe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
 }  // end of paint component



 } // end of Cells

}   // end of tictactoe
```

I have written a code for tic tac toe game. Now I wrote the code in a way so it works as Application and as applet both.
But the problem is that it does not display Images while I run it as applet. Instead of draw image, I tried drawLine and drawOwal methods and it works fine.

But my professor wants I have to run it using image. Can any one give me any solution for this please.

Thanks in advance. Also uploading the code with this post. and please let me know if any one has solution. I need to show the assignment tomorrow ... :(

Comment: @Mike Note the [tag:homework] tag has been retired.

Answer (score 0):

Applet can't write or read local file.

Comment: then how i should display the image?


I thought this is the way that you draw images. I put the image in the same folder too, I even tried paths in different ways, non of them worked

Comment: fn = new File("D:\\Java Projects\\HW9\\images\\tic-tac-toe-O.png");   
               bg = ImageIO.read(fn);
               g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, this);

Comment: Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(filenameOrURL);

Answer (score 0):

Applets are sandboxed so do not have permission to access resources outside of where the applet code originated. Also, don't load the image from the `paintComponent` method. Instead load from the applet `init` method which gets called once:

```
public void init() {
    xImage = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "tictactoeX.png");
    oImage = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "tictactoeO.png");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked, it displays all the images. But now encountered one more problem. When I start game first time, it works fine, but when I restart the game, applet screen comes filled with either all 'X' or all 'O' images. I think it buffers the emage some where and at start if fill the buffered image.

Comment: I would suggest adding new 'JComponent' components with their own 'X' or 'O' image, when you click a cell. This way you can delegate the painting functionality to those components.